# Server Hardware Recommendation for ERP Application

Tags: server

I am building an ERP solution using Microsoft .net and SQL server 2012.  I would expect about 20-30 users and my client would like to buy his own server rather than go with a cloud based server.

Given the performance needs of a small enterprise with about 5 concurrent users using a web application (not directly accessing the server) which is the cheapest or the lowest configuration server that I could recommend.

I am considering if hot swappable components would be essential as the server is used primarily for an ERP and can be taken down if there is a component failure.

I was suggested a Dell Power Edge T20 Server, which seems to fit the client's budget, but not sure if there are better options for that sort of a budget.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would think entry level servers with RAID, Hot swap and if needed with redundant Powersupply would be sufficient for this. Any of the entry level servers with Dell, HP and IBM should fit the bill. To keep budget low, SATA as opposed to SAS hard drives (keep in mind the reduced RPMs) and built-in SATA RAID can help

Comment: +1, First look at the technologies within the server that you could find in an everyday home computer. These technologies, such as SATA RAID or hot swapping, can be big pricing pivot points for larger systems.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the entry level servers do not have RAID at all though, for a data intensive application this would be important is my guess, so a desktop-ish machine with say a RAID 5 (if at all that existis) would do ?

Comment: Most entry level servers (eg: Dell PowerEdge T110 II , HP Proliant ML 10) in India has built in SATA RAID and if ordered with 3 hard disks, can be setup as RAID 5 at a price point aroung 50K Indian Rupees.

Comment: Redundant power supply or hot swappable drives  will cost much more..in the same entry level models

Comment: @Jamess thanks for the info, though I am considering this for a client in Middle East, your advice is very helpful thanks